# how to use use load_file in mysql ? I get a wrong message " Can't get stat of 'D:\w.ini' " !

Tags: mysql

like the title.
I guess it is the matter of file's name. But I try "D://w.init" and "file:///D:\w.ini", I util get this wrong message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My wild guess is that you are running this command on a remote mySQL server, and trying to `LOAD INFILE` a file on your local D:\ drive.

This cannot work, as the mySQL on server side can't access your local D: drive.

You will need to upload the file to your server first.